# Mockito mock method of a static enum

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, mockito

I have an Enum as follows:

```java
public class CSVHandler {

    public enum Table {
        USER("User.csv");

        private final String table;

        Table(String table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return this.table;
        }
    }

    //methods of CSVHandler
}
```

`Table` is used to tell the CSVHandler which files are available.

Now, after I created the interface of the CSVHandler I want to create all my tests before I start implementing them, however, this is where I'm stuck at.

I wan to mock this enum, therfore the CSVHandler doesn't access the .csv-files of the productive environment. I want to isolate the CSVHandler. Hence, the class should access .csv-files which are only for testing purpose.

After some research I learned that Mockito 2.x provides the functionality to test Enums, though I'm missing examples.

Can someone provide a very simple example to show me how I can properly isolate the CSVHandler?

Comment: mocking an enum? what is the use of mocking an enum?

Comment: @Stultuske The purpose of mocking the enum is to ensure that the CSVHandler does not access any files of the productive code. I have created some test.csv files which should be used. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Then you shouldn't pick a solution that "reads" nice, but is absolutely not working for "easy to test". Your code is hard-coupling so many things together that absolutely should not be coupled together. Instead of using an backed-in enum; why not define some interface that denotes the functionality you want? And then use dependency injection to *somehow* get an instance of that interface into your CSVHandler class.
Sure, you might be able to get mocking to work here. But please believe me: you are investing your energy in the wrong place.

Comment: You wrote "hard to test code", and now you want to use mocking hammers to "fix" that problem. Wrong approach. Step back, and rework your production design to be **easy** to test.

Comment: See my updated comment.

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah, I kinda came to the same conclusion => "My approach is wrong". You suggest to define an interface and then using dependency injection. I somewhat understand your solution. Could you provide me with a simple example?

Comment: The interface would be straight forward like `interface LocationProvider { Path getFullPathToXyz(); }` or something. And *how* you then create instances of classes implementing that interface really depends on your overall design, and how you do things already. Thing is: this community isnt really meant for design advice. This is really something that you better discuss with the people on your team.